# Is there a noun-form of the word 'intrinsic'?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a noun-form of the word 'intrinsic'?
If so, what is it?

Intrinsicity?
I suppose I could say 'the intrinsic nature of...', but it makes grammar awkward when there are multiple subjects to your sentence, eg: "In regards to your belief in the intrinsic nature of the insult which lies in calling someone a ***_*__*_***, I'd argue that..."

Comment: This question would benefit greatly from an example sentence.

Comment: Which dictionaries have you checked for related word-forms (Wiktionary, for instance, lists 'intrinsicness')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Innerness' is in the dictionary, but it's probably not satisfying.  You can preserve the 'inner' metaphor with 'kernel,' or maybe 'heart' or 'keep' or something.  'Essence' has more to do with existence.  'Endogenous' leads to 'endogeneity,' which is a term of art in econometrics but might be useful in this context.

Comment: Along with your ideas maybe essence fits in somewhere? Somehow intrinsic feels like essential both without a completely satisfying noun-form.

Comment: This is a suggested work-around rather than a direct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The noun form of the adjective *intrinsic* ("belonging to the inmost constitution or essential nature of a thing") is... *intrinsic*, denoting "an intrinsic quality." [M-W]

I'm not sure why M-W marks the noun form as *obsolete*; it's in current use in the computer graphics industry to describe functions built into a shader (commonly referred to as *shader intrinsics*).

Comment: That doesn't really satisfy the example sentence, wherein the noun form describes the amount of 'intrinsic(ness)'. Still, it's an interesting tid-bit, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is probably *[intrinsicality](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/intrinsicality)*:

> the quality of being intrinsic

(Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

The post with Endogeneity lead me to endogenicity, which seemed to fit my particular case well. The autocorrect here says that this is a misspelling, but it is likely due to it being a low frequency word. Dictionary.com (I don't work for them) recognizes it as it relates to [endogenous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/endogenous), but; in the same vein, sees endogeneity as a misspelling. It might have been what you were looking for...